# Git detached head on newly cloned repo

Tags: git

I just cloned a repo and tried to checkout a branch. The branch is checked out in detached head mode! I don't understand why it should do that. I just cloned the repository.

```
$ git checkout PATCH_branch
Note: checking out 'PATCH_branch'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 896c259... xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I figured perhaps I can create a local branch and make it track the remote. So I did:

```
$ git checkout -b PATCH_branch origin/PATCH_branch
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'PATCH_branch' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/PATCH_branch' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

Could someone please explain what the last bit means? Or why I can't checkout a branch without being detached? I know under certain circumstances I might end up with a detached HEAD, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no `origin/PATCH_branch`.  Instead, there is a tag that is very poorly named, and in your clone, you have checked out that tag, resulting in the detached HEAD.

#### Why this happened

If you consult [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), you will see a sequenced list of possibilities for resolving a symbolic reference name:

> *<refname>*, e.g. *master*, *heads/master*, *refs/heads/master*
>
> A symbolic ref name. E.g. *master* typically means the commit object referenced by *refs/heads/master*. If you happen to have both *heads/master* and *tags/master*, you can explicitly say *heads/master* to tell Git which one you mean. When ambiguous, a *<refname>* is disambiguated by **taking the first match in the following rules**:
>
> 1. If *$GIT_DIR/<refname>* exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for *HEAD, FETCH_HEAD, ORIG_HEAD, MERGE_HEAD* and *CHERRY_PICK_HEAD*);
> 2. otherwise, *refs/<refname>* if it exists;
> 3. **otherwise, *refs/tags/<refname>* if it exists**;

In this particular case, the name `PATCH_branch` is *not* in fact ambiguous, but the rules (especially the parts I put in **bold** text) still apply: if there is a tag named `PATCH_branch`, and neither rule #1 nor rule #2 are able to resolve the name to a commit hash but the tag can, Git can check out the tag, so we don't need to go on to look at rules 4, 5, and 6; but here they are anyway:

> 4. otherwise, *refs/heads/<refname>* if it exists;
> 5. otherwise, *refs/remotes/<refname>* if it exists;
> 6. otherwise, *refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD* if it exists.

Of these six rules, only one—specifically rule 4—will *not* give you a "detached HEAD" checkout.  Since you *did* get a detached HEAD, clearly rule 4 did not apply.

#### Special rules for `git checkout`

Now, `git checkout` has its own additional "rule 4.5", where it will *create* `refs/heads/refname` in some situations.  That extra `git checkout` rule is the rule you were *expecting* to experience here, I believe.

Specifically, `git checkout` will, even *before trying rules 1, 2, and 3*, try rule 4.  If this fails, `git checkout` will then see if it can *create* a local branch based on the existence of exactly one matching remote-tracking branch.  In either of these two cases, rule 4 then applies and `git checkout` *does not* give you a "detached HEAD".  Otherwise `git checkout` goes back and starts over at rule 1.

#### Clones initially have only remote-tracking branches and tags

You mentioned that this is a new clone, and in new clones, there is one (and only one) remote and by default, you get all of its branches as remote-tracking branches.  If the remote is named `origin` (as it usually is), these remote-tracking branches live in the `refs/remotes/origin/` part of your repository's name-space.  You also, by default, get all of the remote's tags, which live in your `refs/tags/` name-space.

#### The last step of `git clone` is `git checkout`

When you run:

```
$ git clone <url>
```

or:

```
$ git clone <url> <destination>
```

Git will connect to the given URL, verify that there is a Git repository there, ask that remote for a list of all branches and tags, and then create a clone repository for you in the given destination directory (or use the last part of the URL to make a default destination name).  In that repository, Git will add a remote named `origin` (or whatever name you specify with `-o`).  It will copy all of their tags to your tags, and copy their branches to your `refs/remotes/origin/` remote-tracking branches (if you specify a different `-o`, modify these names as appropriate).  The resulting repository *has no local branches at all*.

However, at this point, `git clone` invokes `git checkout`, to check out some branch—the one you told it to (`git clone -b`) or, by default, the one your Git got from the remote, usually `master`.  Of course, you don't *have* a local `master` branch, and this is where what I called "rule 4.5" comes in: `git checkout` looks to see if there is an `origin/master`, and of course there is, so your Git makes a new local branch named `master` that tracks remote-tracking branch `origin/master`.<sup>1</sup>  This is, in fact, how you get your `master` branch!

When you ran `git checkout PATCH_branch` you no doubt expected Git to follow this same pattern: there should be an `origin/PATCH_branch`, and your Git should create a new (regular, ordinary, local) branch named `PATCH_branch` based on `origin/PATCH_branch` (which is really `refs/remotes/origin/PATCH_branch`).

But instead, what you have is a tag, `refs/tags/PATCH_branch`.  So the special "create local branch from remote-tracking branch" rule does not apply, and the "early application of rule 4" does not apply either, and we're left with rules 1 and 2 (which do not apply) and then rule 3, and that got you the "detached HEAD" checkout.

#### You *can* create a local branch, but be careful!

Look back over the six rules.  Suppose you have both `refs/heads/PATCH_branch` *and* `refs/tags/PATCH_branch`.  Note that rule 3 normally applies *before* rule 4: *most* Git commands will treat `PATCH_branch` as the *tag*.

Because `git checkout` is special, and applies rule 4 first (instead of after rule 3), you will be able to check out the local branch.  But other Git commands will behave in ways you won't expect, as they will apply rule 3 first.

#### The tag is poorly named

Tag names should probably not contain the word "branch".  Whether you can or should fix this is an administrative question more than a technical one.  Find out who created the tag and why, and see if you can get everyone on your project to agree that this is a bad name and thus to delete it.

---

<sup>1</sup>The names here are admittedly terribly confusing.  The local branch `master` is not a "(remote-)tracking branch", but it is "tracking" another branch.  The *remote-tracking branch* `origin/master` is something your Git stores locally; it's just automatically updated from whatever your Git sees on `origin`, whenever your Git talks with their Git.  So your branch—your `master`—is "tracking" a remote-tracking branch, `origin/master`.  All that *really* means is that your `master` has `origin/master` set as its *upstream*, which is a newer, somewhat better term.  Older Git documentation (pre-version-1.8 or so) does not define *upstream* quite this carefully, though.

Comment: What an explanation! Thank you. That's exactly what it was. A tag.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, when you `git clone` a repository, it will only contain a single branch (usually `master`, but in can be different depending on what `HEAD` refers to in the origin repository). It will also have remote references for the branches the origin repository has (these will be named like `refs/remotes/origin/branchname`). If you then do `git checkout branchname`, it will check out the commit found in `refs/remotes/origin/branchname`, but since that is not a branch (which would be named `refs/heads/branchname`), you get a detached `HEAD` - you're no longer looking at a branch.

To resolve that, you can follow the advice given in the message that `git` showed you `git checkout -b <branchname>`, essentially creating a new branch at the commit you have checked out, or run the command you attempted in your second listing. The caveat with the second command is that you need to get back on a branch first (e.g. `git checkout master`) before that command will succeed. If you had run `git checkout -b <branchname> origin/<branchname>` first, it would have been successful. That will also set up the new branch to "track" the origin branch, so you can do `git push`, `git pull`, etc. with it.

Comment: he can also check `git remote -v` and `git fetch origin`, and that he's pulled the remote branches, too with `git branch -avv

Comment: This would normally be true, but assuming the OP's sequencing is correct, he has a *tag* named `PATCH_branch` which he got during the clone.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `checkout` instead of `clone` to get the repository (tho you could simply be skipping the cloning part for your question).

It would seem that your repo doesn't hold any remote repository to check out to. What's the output of `git remote -v` ?

It should probably the same remote repository called origin, once for fetching and once for pushing. If you don't have any, you should `git remote add <remoteRepo>`

Comment: I'm not using checkout instead of clone. My remotes are fine.